# What is the most efficient or Pythonic way of checking for variable change?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are 3 functions whose return value are list of dictionaries, that are further processed to check if a variable is of certain value.

I'm looking to come up with a generic function that does that but within a timeout, else, return the last obtained value or state.

Is it possible to accommodate that as a single generic function ?

I can do something like below on every function's return value but that's more code repeated.

```
timeout_value = 15
start_time = time.time()

#returns list of dictionaries which is further processed to look out for value is "Approved"
 capture_function_1_return_value = function_1()           
... additional steps to filter and capture the intended value in a variable, like -  function_1_return_value... 
while function_1_expected_state != "Approved":
    if time.time() - start_time > timeout_value:
        print "Timed out!"
        return last obtained state of function_1()

#returns list of dictionaries which is further processed to look out for value is "Delivered"

capture_function_2_return_value = function_2()           
... additional steps to filter and capture the intended value in a variable, like -  function_2_return_value... 
while function_2_expected_state != "Delivered":
    if time.time() - start_time > timeout_value:
        print "Timed out!"
        return last obtained state of function_2()

so on..
```

Comment: To do that you need to somehow run a code in parallel (code waiting for changes and the one that could actually change variable) and the answer will very much depend on what you use to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe somethink like that:

```py
def some_function(*args, **kwargs)->list[dict[Any, Any]]:
    # generates some list
    ...
def some_other_function(*args, **kwargs)->list[dict[Any, Any]]:
    # generates some other list
    ...

def is_in_dict(dict_, value_) -> bool:
    # checks if value_ is in dict_
    ...

def search_with_timeout(data, expected_value = ...,extimeout = 15):
    start = time.time()
    for dict_ in data:
        if is_in_dict(dict_, expected_value):
            return dict_ # or what you want
        if start +timeout >=time.time():
            return dict_ # or what you want

search_with_timeout(some_function(), 'bar')
search_with_timeout(some_other_function(), 'foo')
```

i heard that `while` isn't pythonic style loop.

you can replace
`while True:`
with

```
from itertools import count

for _ in count(0):
    #some code
```

Comment: Awesome, looks more Pythonic..